Running code in terminal using "gcc file.c -o file_copy.c ", and my file disappeared
I was running some old code in terminal and wrote this line :"gcc file.c -o file_copy.c ". After running this line I noticed that file_copy.c seems to have disappeared. I'm not sure why it disappeared, where it went, or how to get it back. If anyone knows how I might be able to get my file back or what happened, I would really appreciate the help.
I ran the line "gcc file.c -o file_copy.c ", I  thought this would compile both of these files and run them, but instead it made the second file disappear.

You defined file_copy.c as the destination for the output by making it the argument to -o. It should not have disappeared, it should have been overwritten by the result of compiling file.c, but if that compilation ended with errors, it may have stopped after truncating or unlinking file_copy.c but before opening it or writing anything to it.

In this case since it did disappear, are there any guesses as to where it may have gone or how to get it back?

It hasn't "gone" anywhere, it doesn't exist anymore. I don't think there is any way to get it back. If there is, it depends on what kind of filesystem you are on. Ext3, NTFS, etc. You could look for tools to recover deleted files, but I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Decent programming IDEs make a backup of source files before compilation. But then if you were using a decent programming IDE, you wouldn't be typing all the command line gunk manually either.

-o specifies the output file, ie the name of the executable. If you name one of your source files there it would be overwritten, though hopefully not without warnings if you had the file open at the same time.
If you received no protests then the source file is now gone and replaced by an executable named file_copy.c, no longer a text file.
Restoring files is system-specific and besides that also off-topic, since questions about such belong on the Super User site.
Best practices involve:

Using programming IDEs which may optionally take copies of files before compiling/linking.
You still have to type in compiler instructions manually at some extent, but basic stuff such as which files to link and where the output goes should be handled by the IDE. It is not something you should do manually or with hand-crafted make files, such evil stuff are things of the past (1990s).

Using version control, which also doubles as backup by its very nature.

General file backup of your PC.


